# How to set up L2TP connection on Android?

Tags: vpn

I and some of my friends are trying to connect to an L2TP connection. We set it directly through VPN options in Android's settings, but the problem is that sometimes 1 username and password gets set up in 1 phone but does not set up in another phone.

Thus I'm looking for an alternative way (e.g. 3rd-party VPN apps?) to set the L2TP connection up there.

Comment: App recommendations should better be asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is.

Are the L2TP settings stored in Google Cloud not syncing between devices?

Is one of the phones Android 12? Android 12 and later no longer let you add a L2TP VPN connection manually from the device settings. Android 12 will still keep your old L2TP settings working if your device upgrades from an earlier Android version.

There were some 3rd party L2TP frontend clients available for Android, but they still used the Android L2TP backend, so wouldn't have helped.

Comment: Perhaps related on Reddit: [VPN Client for Android (Windows L2TP VPN)](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/bp7upw/vpn_client_for_android_windows_l2tp_vpn/)